# transfer signup_data from registrationtbl to userstbl

Tags: php, ajax

Good day does anyone can help me about my problem?
i have a signup_form all the data inputted will insert to my registrationtbl, my problem is the code below just delete the data from registrationtbl. how can i move the data to the userstbl and remove it from the registrationtbl? thank you . hope someone may help me..

the code is also came from one of the topics here..

```
<?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","scouts");

if ( isset($_GET['id']) ) {`enter code here`
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM registration WHERE id='$id'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['idno'] . " " . $row['surname'];
        echo "<br>";
    }


    $row = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (surname, firstname, middlename, gender, idno, password, signup_date) 'SELECT * from registration WHERE id =$id");
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM registration WHERE id='$id'");
    echo "its deleted";
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you have an extra ' in the INSERT sql statement? Also, for safety-sake, specify the columns in your SELECT statement near the bottom in the same order as the INSERT statement.

Comment: What would happen if `$id` contained this string: `20%20union%20select%20concat(version(),0x3a,%20database());`?

Answer (score 0):

why are you using 2 tables:

simply use **users** table only, and add a status field to the table, when user registered the status may be 0, when registration approved change status to 1... so there is no need for 2 tables...

or if u have to use both tables, my suggession is the use of a database trigger to insert value to the second table from 1st.